# Extract a particular cookie from page cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, cookies

I need to extract a particular cookie from page cookies in Javascript. I get them in one long string as a passed variable. String is of the format

```
"xyz=1; abc=2; abc-main=3"
```

I need to extract the value of one particular cookie from this string say "abc". What is the best way to do it, is there any function that directly gives you the cookie value?

I'm thinking of splitting this string with semicolon and then traversing the result array to find a string that starts with "abc="

Comment: I would prefer this jquery plugin to handle cookies.. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good.

You could split semicolon and space and later split again results with equal symbol and create an object with results so you can make access to properties so easy:

```
//cookieString is "xyz=1; abc=2; abc-main=3"
cookieSplit = cookieString.split("; ");
var cookieObject = {};
cookieSplit.forEach( function(value, index) {
   var splitResult = value.split("=");
   cookieObject[splitResult[0]] = splitResult[1];
});
```

Then you can access data using *cookieObject.abc* or *cookieObject["abc"]*

Hope it helps!